# The $1.gz exists in the folder, but it said cannot access, no such file or directory

Tags: unix, shell

I have a script that says

```
gzip -cN "$1" > "$1.gz" | ls -l "$1.gz" | awk '{print $5}'
```

I run it with an argument of `ff`, and I get the error message

```
ls: cannot access ff.gz: No such file or directory
```

But when I subsequently run `ls -l` (manually, from the shell prompt),
I see that `ff.gz` is there. 
What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you do

```
cmd1 | cmd2 …
```

then `cmd1` and `cmd2`
run more or less at the same time. 
If you have a multi-CPU system, they may actually run simultaneously. 
But in any case, they will run concurrently,
with the precise scheduling being determined by factors too complex to allow prediction.

Your `cmd1` is `gzip -cN "$1" > "$1.gz"` 
and your `cmd2` is `ls -l "$1.gz"`. 
Therefore, the `ls` might start running before the `gzip` creates the `"$1.gz"` file.

`ls` doesn’t read from its standard input, so piping into it doesn’t make any sense. 
You probably want to do

```
gzip -cN "$1" > "$1.gz"  &&  ls -l "$1.gz" | awk '{print $5}'
```

i.e., run the `gzip`, and then, if it succeeds, run the `ls -l`.